# How should I replace a number in a JSON file with its MD5 hash using sed command?

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression, json, hashsum

I have a big log file in JSON format containing a line as below example :

```json
{"data_1":210,"target_number":1096748811,"extra_data":66}
{"data_1":0,"target_number":7130881445,"extra_data":56}
{"data_1":1712,"target_number":1098334917,"extra_data":48}
{"data_1":0,"target_number":3062674667,"extra_data":54}
{"data_1":53,"target_number":5110609228,"extra_data":246}
```

I want to replace `target_number`'s value with its MD5 hash in the whole file.

I am trying the `sed` command with basic syntax as below:

```
sed -i 's/target_number/target_number_md5/' input.log
```

The expected output (for the first entry in the example above) is:

```json
{"data_1":210,"target_number":620e25e6f054992308c564cb883e4940,"extra_data":66}
```

Comment: So what happens instead of what you expect?

Comment: That's what you're telling it to do. Do you have the md5 hash stored in a variable? Where does it come from?

Comment: Please add the expected output to your question. Also, where is that `5555`? I can't see it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I Found the answer myself.

```
cat $inputFile | grep -Po '(?<="target_number":)[^,"]+' | while read i ; do
    sed -i "s/$i/$(echo -n $i | md5sum | cut -f 1 -d ' ')/g" $outputFile
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Solving a similar problem, I found this question. The offered solution didn't quite work for me because I wanted to solve it without a loop.

Below is a proof of concept how to solve the problem without a loop:

```
sed -E 's/(.*target_number":)([0-9]+)(.*)/echo "\1$(echo -n \2 | md5sum)\3"/e;s/  -//' "$inputFile"
```

- `-E`: Use extended regular expressions rather than basic regular
  expressions.
- `/e`: This command allows one to pipe input from a shell
  command into pattern space.

For more details check this source: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

Answer (score 0):

The following command uses [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to parse the JSON input (Miller release 6 or later should use `--jsonl` in place of `--json` to read "JSON lines"). It then uses the `put` sub-command to modify the value of the `target_number` key. The modification is done by calling `openssl md5` with the original value passed on standard input. We then clean up the generated string by removing all but the MD5 hash from the response.

```bash
mlr --json put '
    $target_number = system("printf \"" . $target_number . "\" | openssl md5");
    $target_number = sub($target_number, ".*= ", "")' file
```

Would you want to use `md5sum` from GNU coreutils, replace `openssl md5` above with `md5sum --tag`.

By using the `md5` utility (often found on BSD systems), we can avoid `printf` and the pipe:

```bash
mlr --json put '
    $target_number = system("md5 -s \"" . $target_number . "\"");
    $target_number = sub($target_number, ".*= ", "")' file
```

The output of each of the above commands would be as follows, given the example in the question:

```json
{ "data_1": 210, "target_number": "620e25e6f054992308c564cb883e4940", "extra_data": 66 }
{ "data_1": 0, "target_number": "f83d74be3dcb71d53263aefdf08203a9", "extra_data": 56 }
{ "data_1": 1712, "target_number": "56ae797ad2c16813d1a6168d28b58d89", "extra_data": 48 }
{ "data_1": 0, "target_number": "81394a193503036fad53b8a9d6ca2456", "extra_data": 54 }
{ "data_1": 53, "target_number": "6f01490a5dc694e51a69b79f7dd21c24", "extra_data": 246 }
```

Since MD5 hashes are strings, not decimal numbers, they are inserted as strings in the resulting JSON document.

Miller can replace the input file with the generated document (i.e. doing an "in-place" edit) if you use `mlr` with its `-I` option.

Note that each command above uses the value of the original `target_number` in a call to `system()` without sanitising it and that doing so constitutes a code injection vulnerability.